# Reward problem in A2C with multiple simultaneous discrete actions

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, actor-critic-methods, rewards

I've built an A2C model whose actor's network has two different kinds of discrete actions, so the critic would take state and action (note that critic takes 2 actions because in each timestep we will do two kinds of actions) to predict the advantage for each of these two different kinds of actions. However, my problem is when the critic network is about to train itself with discounted rewards. It only has the reward of each timestep, so cannot determine which of the two kinds of our actions contributed more to this reward, so both of its outputs (the advantage for the action of kind 1 and the advantage for the action of kind 2) will be changed in the same direction, so output of critic would be biased with its initialization values. How can I solve this problem, that is, to distinguish between the contribution amount of each of these two kinds of actions to the outcome?

**An example of my problem:**
Consider we have 10 cubes 3 boxes. In each time step, we have to choose between 10 cubes and choose between 3 boxes to place the selected cube in the selected box. So we have 2 kinds of actions here: one to pick a cube and the second to put it in one the boxes. Each box only has the capacity of only 4 cubes, and one of the cubes is so big that don't fit in any of the boxes. The reward of each time step will be the negative number of cubes that are not placed in a box, so because of the bigger cube, the agent won't get reward 0 ever. Consider a scenario that a box already contains 4 cubes and we choose that box to place the chosen cube (one of the small cubes) in it, we can't and the time will proceed. Another scenario is when we choose the bigger cube so no matter which box we choose, we cannot place it and the time will proceed. How the agent can distinguish which of these two kinds of actions contributed more to the reward?